# how to open an article with a new pageload listed with ja_sidenews

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am using ja_orisite template on joomla2.5, in the home page I am loding the articles with the help of Ja_Sidenews module. When i click on the article listed inside Ja_Sidenews, The article is being loaded on the homepage itself. 
my requirement is to Display the article without any of the items of home page.

Comment: contact the developer of JA_Slidenews

Answer (score 1):

In your Ja_Sidenews module option, do you have something like : Article link navigation overwrite or article link ItemID overwrite ?

Basically your problem is that the module keep your home page itemId for your article link.
Sometimes this option is not integrated in the module so you can dig into the code and add the itemID overwrite manually.

I want into the same trouble than you and I just chose another module (DisplayNews) which already has the option.